# Getting to the managed objects in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nstableview

I have an `NSTableView` bound to an `NSArrayController`, which is bound to an `NSManagedObjectContext` with one Entity. How can I programmatically set a property on the object currently selected in the table view? I tried doing it directly through

`[[[documentsController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:[tableView selectedRow]] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"dateProperty"]`

but that gave me an exception:

`-[_NSControllerArrayProxy selection]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79430c0`

I tried to bind table selection to an `NSObjectController` and set the value on that, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `setValue:forKey:`. The message you sent, `setObject:forKey:`, is only for NSMutableDictionaries.